# How to make Chart.js with dynamic months on x-axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to make a Chart.js with a dynamic x-axis that will always use the next 7 months as the ticks for the x-axis.

But I'm having two problems:

1. The lines are not showing on my graph
2. The x-axis is only showing the first and last month, none of the months in-between.

Here is an example I made in paint to show what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

And here is the code I have so far:

```js
/* Build the charts */
var ctx = document.getElementById('ROIchart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Paid Search and Leads',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
    }, {
      label: 'SEO and Content',
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      borderColor: 'green',
      data: [0, 2, 8, 21, 57, 77, 100],
      fill: true,
    }]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'month'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ROIchart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the moment.js library, you can look at the length of your array, and from a starting month generate the months, and then put them as labels

```js
/* Build the charts */
var ctx = document.getElementById('ROIchart').getContext('2d');
var array1 = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
var months = []
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  months.push(moment().year(2020).month(i+1).date(0).startOf('month'))
}
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: months,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Paid Search and Leads',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      data: array1,
    }, {
      label: 'SEO and Content',
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      borderColor: 'green',
      data: [0, 2, 8, 21, 57, 77, 100],
      fill: true,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'month'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<canvas id="ROIchart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not have an X axis that dynamically displays the next 7 months.

Comment: I have already updated my answer, now the x axis is variable, check and tell me

Comment: The JS file I'm using (Chart.bundle.min.js) already has moment.js bundled within it. Are we able to use that instead of calling another instance of moment.js? I tried removing the moments.js CDN script tag but it stopped working.

Comment: The Moment.js version in the bundled build is private to Chart.js so if you want to use Moment.js yourself, it's better to use Chart.js (non bundled) and import Moment.js manually. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html

Comment: @HERRERA, is it possible to display only month, but after December, the year should be displayed?

Comment: January 2021 ... December, January 2022 ... December, January 2023 ... December..., @HERRERA. Observe that I use CSV file, which contains YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Hi @GustavoReis, see this https://jsfiddle.net/kp2gLc1b/7/ , let me know if it works for you

Comment: and you can parse the YYYY-MM-DD with new Date(?).

Comment: It does not work yet with a CSV File. The small code: 

`d3.csv("covid-19.csv").then(makeChart);

function makeChart(dates) 
{
  const dateLabels = dates.map(function (d) 
  {
    return d.date;
  });

  const totalDeathsData = dates.map(function (d) 
  {
    return d.totalDeaths;
  });

  const totalCasesData = dates.map(function (d) 
  {
    return d.totalCases;
  });`

I changed from `array1.length` to `totalDeathsData.length`, from `label: dateLabels` to `labels: months`, and I have `data: totalDeathsData` insteaf of `data: array1`.

Comment: If you want to see my whole code, check: https://gist.github.com/gusbemacbe/4b7cb4efa65c2d4b0087f943e6fb4f87, it comes with a JS file and a CSV file. I use D3 plugin, together with Chartjs and Moment.

Comment: The code in the jsfiddle is for generate automatically the months, in your case when you have the date it's not necessary create the months, you have to parse the date and add it in the months array.

Comment: @GustavoReis is it something like this https://jsfiddle.net/8xrcke9a/1/ ? if you want to show only months (not days) you'll have to sum

Comment: It worked. You did a clean code. I tried `type: 'time'`, `time: unit: 'month'` to display only one unit of each month name. This option broke.

Comment: Yes, because now the axis labels are strings, so the type time will not work, it's time for  you to play with these types of data...., tell me if  you need something more.

Comment: I need just one thing. I want to display only one unit of each month name. Only once.